# How to add a new sensor to webots ros2 plugins?

Tags: webots, ros2

I was wondering how can add a new node type to activate under the `<device>` tag in the URDF file.
Looking in the [webots_ros2 repository](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2), I found that is required to create a header and implementation file accordingly with the [C++ plugin tutorial](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/wiki/Tutorial-Creating-a-Custom-Cpp-Plugin).

Can anybody give me some guidance to include this?
I'm interested in using the [Emitter](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/emitter) and [Receiver](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/receiver) nodes.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

The first possibility is to add the new sensors (`Emitter` and `Receiver`) to the list of supported devices in the `webots_ros2_driver` package. This would require modifying or enhancing the source code of the package. This would allow you to use the sensors in your URDF files without the need for a custom plugin. Please feel free to [open a PR](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/compare) with your contribution if you decide to use this solution. You could use other already implemented devices (`webots_ros2_driver/src/plugins`) as examples.

The second possibility is to create a custom plugin that uses the C controller API to access the devices, configure them and get their values. This would require writing a custom plugin that interfaces with the Webots simulation software. You would then need to add the plugin to the URDF file.

You can create your custom plugin in C++ or Python:

- [Creating a Custom C++ Plugin](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/wiki/Tutorial-Creating-a-Custom-Cpp-Plugin)
- [Creating a Custom Python Plugin](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/wiki/Tutorial-Creating-a-Custom-Python-Plugin)

If you use the plugin in C++, make sure you use the C controller API as the C++ controller API cannot be used anymore since version 2023.0.0 of the package.

Comment: Indeed the plugin way is the one that I'm following. I currently have a dev-stage branch in C++, current tests are presenting a struct data issue with the return of the `wb_emitter_get_data()` function to publish the output as a topic. I in the following weeks I will publish the resultant code.